# How to pick the largest number in a matrix of lists in python?

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization

I have a list-of-list-of-lists,  where  the first two act as a "matrix",  where I can access the third list as

```
list3 = m[x][y]
```

and the third list contains a mix of strings and numbers, but each list has the same size & structure.  Let's call a specific entry in this list The Number of Interest. This number always has the same index in this list!

What's the **fastest** way to get the 'coordinates'  (x,y) for the list that has the largest Number of Interest in Python?

Thank you!

(So really, I'm trying to pick the largest number in m[x][y][k]   where k is fixed, for all x & y,  and 'know' what its address is)

Comment: how do you know what element in the third list you are interested in?

Comment: Are the nunbers of interest (or the lists holding them) in any sort of preexisting order? If not, the fastest you'll get is O(n^3) with `for i in m: for j in i: for k in j:` (not exact code).

Comment: I'm always interested in the same element because of the way I've set it up.

Comment: @FooBah There's no need to sort to find the max.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
max((cell[k], x, y)
    for (y, row) in enumerate(m)
    for (x, cell) in enumerate(row))[1:]
```

Also, you can assign the result directly to a couple of variables:

```
(_, x, y) = max((cell[k], x, y)
                for (y, row) in enumerate(m)
                for (x, cell) in enumerate(row))
```

This is O(*n*<sup>2</sup>), btw.

Answer (score 3):

```
import itertools

indexes = itertools.product( xrange(len(m)), xrange(len(m[0]))
print max(indexes, key = lambda x: m[x[0]][x[1]][k])
```

or using numpy

```
import numpy
data = numpy.array(m)
print numpy.argmax(m[:,:,k])
```

In you are interested in speeding up operations in python, you really need to look at numpy.

Comment: +1. Any solution is O(mn) by its very nature, but the constant factor can be high with Python's method call overhead. Numpy can speed things up by a large factor.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming "The Number of Interest" is in a known spot in the list, and there will be a nonzero maximum,

```
maxCoords = [-1, -1]
maxNumOfInterest = -1
rowIndex = 0
for row in m:
    colIndex = 0
    for entry in row:
        if entry[indexOfNum] > maxNumOfInterest:
            maxNumOfInterest = entry[indexOfNum]
            maxCoords = [rowIndex,colIndex]
        colIndex += 1
    rowIndex += 1
```

Is a naive method that will be O(n<sup>2</sup>) on the size of the matrix.  Since you have to check every element, this is the fastest solution possible.

@Marcelo's method is more succulent, but perhaps less readable.

Comment: It takes a fair amount of syntactical knowledge to understand the logic.  I'd use it, but probably not if I was attempting to teach someone why the code worked if they weren't well versed in python.

Comment: List comprehensions present a vastly superior way to think about data manipulation than the traditional looping approaches. They are one of the first concepts I would teach a new Python programmer.

Comment: I think @MarceloCantos wins on the readability count. For one, you could really use enumerate rather then manual counting.

Comment: Teaching python, not teaching the concept in a language-agnostic way, like most CS is taught.  Again, it's clearly a more pythonic solution, but entry level programmers need to understand why the logic works before they can understand why there is a better way to do something in a particular language.  I've walked people learning programming through loops, sometimes adding extra variables that aren't needed to illustrate a point, and it seems to work better than trying to explain my one-liner for the same problem to them.  To each his own, I suppose.